# How to enforce a Square number constraint in Microsoft Solver foundation OML?

Tags: excel, ms-solver-foundation

I want to limit the result to only square numbers ( I am using excel plugin). How do I enforce this?

As in, Minimize Goal X subject to a condition that X is a square number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an adjustable cell, Y and restrict it to be an integer. Set the equation that you are trying to minimize equal to Y^2.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Even though you mistook that I am working on Excel Solver plugin (I was actually trying to solve this using Microsoft Solver Foundation http://www.amsterdamoptimization.com/msf.html)

But the idea helped though!! I used your suggestion in OML and it worked!

For others looking for a similar solution in OML, simply add another decision Y of Integer domain and add a constraint that Y = X*X. Like this:

Model[
 
Decisions[
....
], 
Decisions[
Integers[10000,31622],y
],

Constraints[ 
x == y*y,
...
]

]

Answer (score 2):

Mark's answer helped. The solution in OML would look like

```
Model[ 

Decisions[ .... ],  

Decisions[  
Integers[10000,31622],y  
],  

Constraints[  
x == y*y,  
... ]  

]
```